# Laravel Eloquent Relation display in ajax undefined

Tags: php, ajax, laravel

This id use another table wants to relation menu_catagory_id for manu name display

```
$(document).on('click', '.edit_data',function() { 
    var menu_id = $(this).attr('id');
    var _token = $('input[name="_token"]').val();
    $.ajax({ 
        url: '{{ url("menu/view") }}', 
        method: "POST", 
        data: {menu_id:menu_id, _token : _token}, 
        dataType:"json", 
        success:function(data){ 
            if(data) { 
                console.log('Here'); 
                $('#result').html(''); 
                $('#result').append('<select id="res"></select>'); 
                $.each(data, function(i,val) { 
                    console.log(val.menuCategory); 
                }); 
            } 
        } 
    }); 
});
```

i wants to relation two table and display data in console

//view menu

```
public function view(Request $request){
    $tryy=Menu_menucategory_mapping::where('menu_id',$request->menu_id)->get(); return $tryy; 
}
```

display data by ajax console Eloquent Relationship

```
public function menuCategory() { 
    return $this->belongsTo('App\MenuCategory'); 
}
```

relation with `menucategory table`

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Load your data just like :

```
public function view(Request $request){
$tryy=Menu_menucategory_mapping::with('menuCategory')->where('menu_id',$request->menu_id)->get(); 
 return $tryy;
```

}

Comment: $.each(data, function(i,val) { 
                    console.log(val.menuCategory); 
                }); 
its not work